# Can't center image in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I want to center an image in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\author{[redacted]}
\title{Test Exercise 1}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item Here is the scatter plot where advertising is the independent variable
    and sales the dependent variable:

    \begin{figure}[h]
      \centering
      \includegraphics{11}
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The outcome is not what I want though. Here is a screenshot:

[image: diagnostic screenshot]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: it seems that the size  of image  is big so it prevent centering

Comment: can you try with `\includegraphics[scale=.5]{11}` or `\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{11}`?

Comment: try `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}`  (using a `figure}[h]` in a list is a bit odd, and generally `[h]` should be avoided as it makes it more likely the figure goes to the end of the document)

Comment: It's centred, it's just too large as @touhami says. If you imagine the image scaling up, it starts in the centre and grows and grows until it hits the immovable object of the left-hand margin, meaning the only thing it can do is spill gradually more and more into the right hand margin, which is why it looks off-centre. If you halved the size of the image it would be centred. If you doubled it, you would see more clearly what was happening, as much of the image would be off the page and invisible

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401559/134144

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{11}
\end{figure}
```

the `[h]` here mostly has the effect of specifying that the figure can not be `t`op `b`bottom or on a `p`age of floats so most likely it goes to the end of the document leaving the paragraph above referring to nothing.

It would be better to use

```
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{11}
\end{center}
```

So that the image is part of the list content not a floating insert, and also so that it is scaled to be small enough to be centred within the textblock of the list. (You can use `[width=\linewidth]` if you want it the full width of the text block)

Comment: Neat way of ensuring as much of the page width can be taken up as possible!