# Aligning image caption within itemize environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, itemize

I am trying to align the beginning of an image caption with the bullet point given by `\item`.  I have included the portion of my code below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}
                          
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{float}
                
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Super-Equilateral Isosceles Triangle: description
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{super-equilateral isosceles triangle with division plane.JPG.png}
\caption{Super-equilateral isosceles triangle. The predicted division plane is marked with a red line.}
\label{fig: Super-equilateral isosceles triangle. The predicted division plane is marked with a red line.}
\end{figure} 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

At present, the caption starts too far to the left as shown below.

[image]

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401559/134144

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a non-float for your figure, you might as well place it inside a `minipage` in order to limit the horizontal width of the float box. The width here is fixed to `\linewidth` - the natural width within the `itemize`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Super-Equilateral Isosceles Triangle: description
  
  \medskip
  
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image}
      \caption{Super-equilateral isosceles triangle. The predicted division plane is marked with a red line.}
    \end{figure}
  \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you don't wish to add an accompanying figure caption, you don't need a `figure` environment. You can just place the image inside (say) a `center` environment:

```
  \item Super-Equilateral Isosceles Triangle: description
  
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{example-image}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: This worked very well. Just curious, what does the command `\medskip` do?

Comment: `\medskip` inserts a `med`ium vertical `skip` (equivalent to `\medskipamount`). There's also `\smallskip` and `\bigskip` (inserting a `\smallskipamount`/`\bigskipamount` vertical space).